# I am facing issues with fontawesome on my page

Tags: html, css

When I run a project on a local environment and when I try to run the following link, http://localhost/Updated/webmaster/index.php , I am supposed to click and open the landing page and the pages as well on the DASHBOARD but the words are available though on trying to open the landing page and the pages, they are inactive and for this reason I can not open them at all.

below is my piece of code for the sidebar.php

```
<body id="page-top">

    <!-- Page Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar">

            <!-- Sidebar - Brand -->
            <a class="sidebar-brand d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" href="index.php">
                <div class="sidebar-brand-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-university"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="sidebar-brand-text mx-3">BU Admin <sup></sup></div>
            </a>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider my-0">

            <!-- Nav Item - Dashboard -->
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">
                    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
                    <span>Dashboard</span></a>
            </li>

            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider">

            <!-- Heading -->
            <div class="sidebar-heading">
                Updates
            </div>

            <!-- Nav Item - Pages Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    <i class="fas fa-folder"></i>
                    <span>Landing Page</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Sections</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="slide.php">Slide</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="event.php">Events</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="news.php">News</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- Nav Item - Utilities Collapse Menu -->
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseUtilities"
                    aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseUtilities">
                    <i class="fas fa-folder"></i>
                    <span>Pages</span>
                </a>
                <div id="collapseUtilities" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingUtilities"
                    data-parent="#accordionSidebar">
                    <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
                        <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Pages:</h6>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="campus.php">Campus</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="gallery.php">Gallery</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="school.php">School</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="department.php">Department</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="programs.php">Program</a>
                        <a class="collapse-item" href="publication.php">publication</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>


            <!-- Divider -->
            <hr class="sidebar-divider d-none d-md-block">

            <!-- Sidebar Toggler (Sidebar) -->
            <div class="text-center d-none d-md-inline">
                <button class="rounded-circle border-0" id="sidebarToggle"></button>
            </div>

        </ul>
        <!-- End of Sidebar -->

        <!-- Content Wrapper -->
        <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">

            <!-- Main Content -->
            <div id="content">

                <!-- Topbar -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">

                    <!-- Sidebar Toggle (Topbar) -->
                    <button id="sidebarToggleTop" class="btn btn-link d-md-none rounded-circle mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Topbar Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                       

                        <div class="topbar-divider d-none d-sm-block"></div>

                        <!-- Nav Item - User Information -->
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown no-arrow">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="userDropdown" role="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="mr-2 d-none d-lg-inline text-gray-600 small">Administrator</span>
                                <img class="img-profile rounded-circle"
                                    src="img/undraw_profile.svg">
                            </a>
                            <!-- Dropdown - User Information -->
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--grow-in"
                                aria-labelledby="userDropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">
                                    <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-sm fa-fw mr-2 text-gray-400"></i>
                                    Logout
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </nav>
                <!-- End of Topbar -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by "they are inactive"? You mean the links do not respond to clicking on them? Or that there is an error/problem when you visit the pages at those links? Try to be clearer and more specific about how the code is behaving please, so that we can understand the root cause of the issue. You can [edit] your post. Thanks

Comment: the problem is with visiting the landing page and the pages. I AM SUPPOSEDE TO CLICK IN THE "LANDING PAGE" and "PAGES"  so that I can open the content in them ie under the landing page, i have Slides, Events and News. so i want to reactivate the dashboard icons in that when i click on "Landing page", the list is droped down for me to select either i want slides, news or events

Comment: Ok. So what is stopping you from doing that. What do you mean by "reactivate them"? What is actually happening in your code? It's still unclear specifically what techinical problem you are having. If we put the code you've provided into a live demo like this: https://jsfiddle.net/dxjp570e/ then we can see that the links in there will all cause navigation to the URL specified in the `href`. Is that not happening for you? What exactly is happening instead? I strongly suspect you haven't given us a [mre] of the issue, but there is still very little clarity or specifics provided. See also [ask].

Comment: the icons are not active

Comment: What icons? The code you've shown does not include any icons. You only showed HTML. Perhaps there is some JS or CSS missing from what you've provided? You mentioned using fontawesome?? What version? And what do you mean by "active"? Do you mean "clickable"? If you could stop being vague and start being specific, as I've already asked, we could make a lot more progress a lot faster. Programming is also about small details and clear, specific functionality.

Comment: If we add the latest fontawesome to the demo I made earlier we get this: https://jsfiddle.net/hsjcnfva/ As you can see here, the icons are fully visible and clickable (which you'd expect since they are within the `<a href...` tags). So we still cannot reproduce any issue. we can't fix issues if we can't see or reproduce them